# For loop with if statement not iterating over entire array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I feel embarrassed asking such a fundamental question. But if it is a fundamental or simple gap in my js knowledge, I would rather get an explanation as to why so I can start making good habits sooner rather than later.

I have a function that takes in a string as an argument and compares it with array values.

```
function validateHello(greetings){
var hello = ['hello','ciao','salut','hallo', 'hola', 'ahoj','czesc'];
  for(var i = 0; i < hello.length; i++){
    if(greetings === hello[i]){ 
      return true;
    }else{ 
      return false;
    }

   }

}
```

It appears that every time I run this for loop, it only checks the first array `hello[0]` and then it appears to break. How can I stop this from happening? I tried using `continue;`after return true but that didn't fix it either. I feel like I should know this, but I am totally brainfarting and cannot figure out why.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because of your `return false` statement, you should put it outside the loop and remove the `else` statement:

```
function validateHello(greetings){
var hello = ['hello','ciao','salut','hallo', 'hola', 'ahoj','czesc'];
  for(var i = 0; i < hello.length; i++){
    if(greetings === hello[i]){ 
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Explanation: When the `greetings` argument is not equal to the first element, `'hello'`, then the code would execute the `else` statement, which returns `false` and stops the function execution.

Answer (score 2):

Your `return` statements are breaking out of the function. If you remove the `return` statements, it'll loop through the whole array (although it looks like you're not actually doing anything, so I don't know how you'll know that).

If you simply want to return true if `greetings` is in the array, then this is what you're looking for:

```
function validateHello(greetings){
var hello = ['hello','ciao','salut','hallo', 'hola', 'ahoj','czesc'];
  for(var i = 0; i < hello.length; i++){
    if(greetings === hello[i]){ 
      return true;
    } 
   }
    return false;
}
```

Note that the return false has been moved to outside of the loop. This way it'll return true as soon as `greetings` is found, otherwise it'll finish the loop and then return false.

Answer (score 0):

I add notes in your code and change the wrong part.
Remove the `else` block and put the `return false;` out of the `for` loop. This will make a full `for` loop. Only the condition of `if` statement is `true`,the `for` loop will `return`. And if the `for` loop is over without a return , the `return false;` statement below will be executed.

```
function validateHello(greetings){
    var hello = ['hello','ciao','salut','hallo', 'hola', 'ahoj','czesc'];
    for(var i = 0; i < hello.length; i++){
        if(greetings === hello[i]){ 
            return true;
        }
        /* if you add a else block here. it means you want your 'else condition' to be checked in every single loop. Since 'if statement has a 'return' and 'else' statement has a 'return'. So if there is a 'else' here, no matter what condition you add , your for loop can only be executed once.  */
    }
    return false; // only the for loop is over and no return. this statement will be executed.
}
```